# jQuery check if any of selected inputs is empty

Tags: jquery, if-statement

How in a simples way would I test, if any of selected inputs is empty?

I get my inputs this way:

```
$myinputs = $('.inputstotest');
```

and would test single input with:

```
if ( $.trim($this.val()) == '' )
```

but how to test a group and return true if all are not empty or false if any (at least one) is empty?

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest:

```
var someEmpty = $('.inputstotest').filter(function(){
    return $.trim(this.value).length === 0;
}).length > 0;
```

With the above `someEmpty` will be a Boolean, `true` if there are `inputs` of that class-name with a trimmed-`value` equal to zero, `false` if no inputs of that class-name have a trimmed-`value` of a length equal to zero.

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = true;
$('.inputstotest').each(function() {
    if ($.trim($(this).val())) == '') {
        result = false;
        return false; // Terminate the .each loop
    }
});
return result;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
var $myinputs = $('.inputstotest');
if($myinputs.filter(function() { return $.trim(this.value) == ''; }).length > 0) {
    //There is at least one empty input
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var invalidInputs = $('.inputstotest').filter(function() {
    return $.trim(this.value) == '';
});

if (invalidInputs.length > 0) {
   //some were invalid
   invalidInputs.after('<span>Please enter a value!</span>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you had each input have the same class eg. `class="checkInput"` the used jquery to cycle through them using the code below:

```
var anyBlank = false;
$('.checkInput').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        anyBlank = true;
    }
});

if(anyBlank){
    alert('There is at least 1 input that is blank');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery each function

```
$(".inputstotest").each(function(){});
```

Heres a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Beyyd/1/