# jQuery check if all of selected inputs are empty

Tags: jquery, if-statement

What is the simplest way to test if all of selected inputs are empty?

I get my inputs this way:

```
$myinputs = $('.inputstotest');
```

and would test single input with:

```
if ( $.trim($this.val()) == '' )
```

but how to test a group and return true if all are empty or false if any (at least one) is not empty?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery check if any of selected inputs is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751631/jquery-check-if-any-of-selected-inputs-is-empty)

Comment: @Neal It's not a duplicate, it's the opposite.

Comment: @Barmar not really... looks exactly the same, with the same answers...

Comment: @Neal - is oposite - the second one tests for "if any empty" and this tests for "if all empty"

Comment: @Barmar any and all are not opposites

Comment: @Ankit "empty" and "not empty" are opposites.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var $myinputs = $('.inputstotest');

var allEmpty = $myinputs.filter(function () {
    return $.trim(this.value) != '';
}).length == 0;

console.log(allEmpty);
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/brkXk/)

*( In order to test, enter some values in the HTML markup, run the fiddle again and check in the console.)*

Answer (score 2):

This is just like my answer to the previous question, except the sense of the test is reversed.

```
var result = true;
$('.inputstotest').each(function() {
    if ($.trim($(this).val())) != '') {
        result = false;
        return false; // Terminate the .each loop
    }
});
return result;
```

Comment: @Ankit Thanks, you're correct. I fixed the same typo in the other answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$(".inputstotest input").each(function(){
        if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
          //do something
        }
        else{
             //do something
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think the part he's having trouble with is what _something_ should be to get his true/false result.